# Über das Verb „gelten“ im Satz „Goethe gilt als das Genie der deutschen Literatur“

Tags: grammar, verb, grammatical-case

Ich habe eine Frage zum Verb *gelten* im Satz

> Goethe gilt als das Genie der deutschen Literatur

Ich denke, dass das Verb *gelten* im Satz mit doppelter Nominativ-Ergänzung ist, nämlich *Goethe* und *das Genie*. Wenn ich richtig vermute, vestehe ich nicht, warum das Verb *gelten* nicht [hier](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=38#zwei_mal_nominativ) ist.

Comment: Weil die Liste unvollständig ist. Siehe mehr unter "Der Gleichsetzungsnominativ (Prädikatsnominativ)" bei [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominativ).

Comment: @Stephie, ah.. also denke ich gut, es gibt andere verben mit doppelten Nominativ-Ergänzung!! Danke ;)

Comment: @Stephie, ich habe das Verb "gefeiert (als) werden", es ist auch mit doppelten Nominativ-Ergänzung, nicht wahr?

Comment: @mle: »Ich denke gut« ist keine gebräuchliche deutsche Phrase. Da ich aber nicht genau weiß, was du damit eigentlich sagen willst, kann ich dir leider auch nicht sagen, wie man das, was du ausdrücken möchtest, besser sagen könnte. Meinst du mit »wenn ich gut denke« vielleicht »wenn ich richtig vermute«?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, ja, hast du Recht, »wenn ich richtig vermute« ist besser. ;) Danke!

Comment: Deine Frage ist auch unvollständig, denn sie ist nicht verständlich ohne dass man dem Link folgt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Vermutung ist richtig, beide Satzteile stehen im Nominativ. Das wird deutlich, wenn man an ihrer Stelle Maskulina mit Artikel einsetzt:

> Der Hund gilt als der beste Freund des Menschen.

Zur Frage, warum die verlinkte Tabelle auf mein-deutschbuch.de das nicht aufführt, kann ich mich nur Stephies Kommentar anschließen: *Weil die Liste unvollständig ist.* :-) Möglicherweise will sie nur die Verben aufführen, bei denen der zweite Nominativ ‚nackt‘ ist, also ohne *als*. Wikipedia [listet auch solche Verben auf](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominativ#Der_Gleichsetzungsnominativ_.28Pr.C3.A4dikatsnominativ.29).

Es gibt noch weitere Fälle, die auch bei Wikipedia nicht berücksichtigt sind. Beispielsweise kann *nennen* mit einem doppelten Akkusativ stehen; setzt man das ins Passiv, wird ein doppelter Nominativ daraus:

> Man nennt den Hund den besten Freund des Menschen.
>
> Der Hund wird der beste Freund des Menschen genannt.

Comment: Man sollte noch ergänzen, dass "als" immer den Fall des Objektes annimmt, auf das es sich bezieht (auch als Attribut). Möglicherweise sind deshalb Verben, die mit "als" konstruieren, nicht aufgelistet.