# “Das ist sein Pass.“ Is this sentence right?

Tags: grammar, possessive-pronoun

> Das ist sein Pass.

In this sentence, why is *sein*, not *seinen*? Pass is a masculine word. I’m a little confused!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it's nominative, not accusative.

Properly speaking it's a predicative nominative. It's part of the predicate but complements the subject.

```
[Subject] [Predicate]
{pronoun} {copular verb} {noun phrase}
Das       ist            sein Pass.
```

This subject complement has to be in the same case as the subject, nominative that is.
Indicator for the subject complement is the use of the copular verb *sein*. There are a few more words that have the same or similar function (for instance, *werden*).

For reference, an example for accusative would be:

> Ich gebe ihm seinen Pass.

Comment: Thank you! I just get to learn German. The gender and cases in German made me upset.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I didn't use the term "subject", did I? I added a short explanation on this, though.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I wouldn’t be sure. I wouldn’t know how to say which nominative is subject and which is predicative. Hence I would *always* assume the subject to be placed before *sein* and the predicative afterwards — and therefore assume that the speaker in ‘sein Pass ist das’ is showing the listener what *his pass* is. ‘Das ist sein Pass und nicht sein Notizbuch’ vs ‘Sein Pass ist das und nicht das daneben.’

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Fair enough. I guess I have to reconsider that point. I mean, it's not wrong but not an explanation either.

Comment: Nominative goes always after **sein, bleiben, werden**. Just to make things complete.

Comment: @BarthZalewski If I'm not mistaken there are a few more with similar function that aren't real copular verbs, though. Couldn't find a list, but it's not that important anyways. A few for English are mentioned [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/copular_verb), but I guess none of them can take a nominative but adjectives only.

Comment: @Barth Zalewski, Em1: At least _heißen_ is missing. We had some discussion about double nominative here: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23292 See [the Wikipedia article mentioned there](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominativ#Der_Gleichsetzungsnominativ_.28Pr.C3.A4dikatsnominativ.29) for even more verbs with _als_, and see http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23781 for verbs with double accusative that may become double nominative in the passive.

Comment: Very good answer.