# Why is "Luke, ich bin dein Vater" correct instead of "Luke, ich bin deinen Vater"?

Tags: noun, accusative

With my translation tools / online courses I see that the phrase "Luke, ich bin dein Vater" is correct. However, I do not understand why we shouldn't use "deinen". Isn't Darth Vader the direct object of the sentence? Isn't this an example of the accusative case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“Das ist sein Pass.“ Is this sentence right?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24071/das-ist-sein-pass-is-this-sentence-right)

Comment: Just noting that this is ontopic here. If op has confused the cases, then a conjugation table doesn't help.

Comment: I'd be surprised if in any language the "object of the *to be* verb" would be a  direct object, thus I don't see why this is related to German.

Comment: I agree with @infinitezero - this question should have been closed as duplicate instead.

Comment: I also agree that the question should have been closed as a duplicate...I'll flag the moderators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct to make a difference between possessive pronouns and possessive determiners (articles). But for "ich bin dein Vater" (which is correct) the point is, that the complements of the verb "sein" are not the subject (nominative) and an accusative object (as for *haben, nehmen, kennen* and most of the verbs). "Sein" has a *subject* and a *predicative complement*, and both of them are nominative, as in

> Er ist ein gut**er** Fahrer.